# How can I show the following symmetric matrix is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, symmetric-matrices

**Question**

Suppose that I have an n by n square matrix $A$ whose elements are all nonnegative, and its diagonal elements are strictly less than 1. Further, for any vector $p$ with $0<p_i<1$, $p>A^Tp$, i.e. $p_i>(A^Tp)_i$. How do I show that $diag(3-4A+2A^TA)-(A+A^T-A^TA)$ is invertible?

I managed to solve the 2 by 2 case by comparing common terms in the determinant. But even a 3 by 3 matrix would make the comparison infeasible. Grateful for any comments and suggestions!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion caused. Here I'm taking $p$ as a vector with all elements being positive. We can think of $p$ as a price vector. Then A is the input-output matrix. Therefore, $p>A^Tp$ ensures that for each unit sold, the input cost will be smaller than the sale price. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: What’s the diag function? Which symmetric matrix are you testing?

Comment: I used $diag()$ to denote the matrix which keeps only the diagonal elements of the first part, i.e. $(3 - 4A + 2A^TA)$ while leaving the off-diagonal elements 0. So the final expression I have in the original post would be symmetric, i.e. $diag(3−4+2^)−(+^−^)$. This is the one I'm testing. Hope this clarifies!

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant!

Comment: It might be helpful to look instead at the matrix $B=I-A$ and its transpose. That change of perspective should simplify the problem format.

Comment: @MathWonk Thanks for the suggestion! While this indeed reduces the expression to $2 diag(B^TB)+B^TB$, I'm still struggling to show the invertibility. Appreciate any help!

Comment: Perhaps you can show that the latter expression $M$ is a positive definite matrix; i,e $v^t Mv>0$ for all $v$. Try looking at numerical examples.